# How do i change the orders of the activities in the manifest file?

Tags: kotlin

So i clearly want the login activity to pop up first instead of the main one!!??

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Eventr">  
        <activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: The launcher will start the activity that is exported and reacts on the respective intents. And currently this is your main activity.

Answer (score 1):

The order of elements in the manifest doesn't matter, and the build tools don't make assumptions about which `activity` is your main one. You explicitly specify that yourself, with that `intent-filter` you see under `.MainActivity` - that tells the system to make that activity available to the system launcher. You also need the `exported="true"` attribute.

So if you want `.Login` as your main activity, move that intent filter into the other activity's tag, and export it. Or you could just switch the names around